# jquery Как сменить тип тега оставив все остальные атрибуты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Предположим есть вот такой тег в дом дереве. `<button class="page-numbers current" data-href="2">2</button>`

Можно ли как-то сменить его на `<span class="page-numbers current" data-href="2">2</span>` не создавая новий Нод элемент ? Просто сменить тип тега. Возможно ли это ?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, тип тега определяет саму природу DOM-элемента.

Comment: тег нельзя, атрибуты можно

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = $('.page-numbers').text();
$('.page-numbers').click(function(){
$(this).replaceWith($('<span class="page-numbers current" data-href="2">' + text + '</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="page-numbers current" data-href="2">2</button>
```

Comment: Так это замена элемента, а не тега существующего элемента. Никто же не говорит, что нельзя заменить элемент в DOM целиком с сохранением атрибутов, но вопрос ведь не об этом.

Comment: Да, вы правы, этот код меняет элемент, но не тег.
Предположу что автор не улавливает между ними разницу, поэтому так написал.

Comment: Потому и спросил дословно: "Можно ли как-то сменить его на не создавая новий нод элемент?"

Comment: Упс, не заметил))) читаю между строк... Приношу свои извинения если кого обидел ответом.

Comment: @Simon Слушай, ну а если измененный элемент сохранить в localstorage, а потом достать его с заменой - тогда сменится тег?

Comment: "ну а если измененный элемент сохранить в localstorage", -- измененный в каком плане? Не совсем понял мысль. Вы же именно сам тег у существующего элемента не можете сменить. Ну и доставая его и заменяя, Вы смените один элемент на другой.

Comment: Понял, тогда значит не вариант получается